# libCurl C++ on Eclipse - Undefined symbols

Tags: c++, eclipse, libcurl

I installed libCurl, and I'm trying to build the sample 'simple.c' from the curl website directly in Eclipse, but I get the following errors:

```
make all 
Building file: ../simple.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"simple.d" -MT"simple.d" -o "simple.o" "../simple.c"
Finished building: ../simple.c

Building target: Test_SimpleCurl
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
gcc  -o "Test_SimpleCurl"  ./simple.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from:
      _main in simple.o
  "_curl_easy_init", referenced from:
      _main in simple.o
  "_curl_easy_perform", referenced from:
      _main in simple.o
  "_curl_easy_setopt", referenced from:
      _main in simple.o
  "_curl_easy_strerror", referenced from:
      _main in simple.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Test_SimpleCurl] Error 1
```

This is a simple "new C++ project > new File" in Eclipse.
When I build, Eclipse also generates some files in the debug folder.
Here's the content of 'Makefile'

```
-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: Test_SimpleCurl

# Tool invocations
Test_SimpleCurl: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross GCC Linker'
    gcc  -o "Test_SimpleCurl" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(EXECUTABLES)$(OBJS)$(C_DEPS) Test_SimpleCurl
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

I would assume I'm missing linker or compiler flags, but I don't have any idea on where to add these flags in this project.

Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: As far I can see,  you've been missing to specify `libcurl.a` to be linked with your project.

Comment: How do I link it I side of eclipse?

Comment: _"How do I link it I side of eclipse?"_ It's described in the dupe. Add the path to the library, and `curl`.